# Animating background doesn't show up at the place I wish

Tags: html, css

I overwrite my website to be responsive, now I've added also some new feautures. I added a new animated background but now it doesn't showing up at the place I wish for. Also I've edit the most of it with flex for my school project, I've must make it with flex we can use only flex for the school project

```css
.bg {
  animation: slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  left: -50%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  position: fixed;
  right: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }
}

.site1 {
  background: #4B9ACC;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100em;
}

div.wrap content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    div.wrap-content {
        flex-flow: row;
    }
    nav, aside {
        flex: 0 0 10rem;
    }
    
    body{
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
        background-color: black;
    }
    div.wrap-content {
        flex: 1 auto;
    }
}

main {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-content">
    <main>
        <div class="site1" id="3">
          <div class="bg"></div>
          <div class="bg bg2"></div>
          <div class="bg bg3"></div>
          <h1 class="title">Welcome to my Website!</h1>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

Comment: _but now it doesn't showing up at the place I wish for.._ How should we know which place you are talking about?

Comment: It's this place I posted, this animation showed above of all sites I've created

Comment: Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you continue to ask unclear and downvoted questions, you will end up with a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: I'm still not sure of the problem, do you want the animation to be the entire background. or do you want a bigger gap between the top of the page and the content? OR, do you only want the animation at the top?

Comment: I have multiple sites with different backgroundcolors I've put this animation in in this site that I wish for and now it appears at the top. To say it with your words I want a bigger gap between the top of the page and the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try this One!

```css
.bg {
  animation: slide 3s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, #6c3 50%, #09f 50%);
  left: -50%;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  position: fixed;
  right: -50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.bg2 {
  animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

.bg3 {
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }
}

.site1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
h1 {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="site1" id="3">
  <div class="bg"></div>
  <div class="bg bg2"></div>
  <div class="bg bg3"></div>
  <h1 class="title">Welcome to my Website!</h1>
</div>
```

Just add this CSS

```
.site1 {
  background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: send me screenshot I use some css to fixed it